# Multiple requirements of a query

Tags: c#, database, linq

not certain how to word this but here goes. I'm using linq to write the service layer for a server. I've already got my database setup and I've inherited classes from that using an Entity layer (which will be replaced with a WCF layer to correctly make use of JSON - a software requirement for this project). I am currently writing a method called "JoinCalendar" ( a major part of the application) where a I want to certify that a user is valid to join the calendar.

Here's the code for startes

```
public bool JoinCalendar(int famID, string email)
{   
 using (FamilySchedulerEntities db = new FamilySchedulerEntities())
 {
   var checkUser = (from u in db.Users
                    where u.familyID.Equals(famID) && !u.emailAddress.Equals(email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    select u).FirstOrDefault();

  if( checkuser != null){ return false}
  else
  {
    //stuff
    return true;
  }
```

The aim of this method is take the familyID (the Identity field of a group of users) of the calendar the user is trying join and that users emailaddress (the unique ID for each user). I want to perform two different checks from that query.

Firstly: I want to check that the familyID is a valid one (ie. make sure the familyID is an actual value stored on the database)
Secondly: Check that email address of the user does not match a user who is registered to any family
Thirdly: Can I use the "!" operator in a linq query oris it bad practise/etiquette

kind regards,
Simon Johnson

PS. Only been using linq (and in fact writing a database application) for less than a week so please keep this newbie friendly. Ideally I need a super elegenat solution because the client to this server may be connected using a cellular (ie. not wifi) connection and I need to keep data transmission to an absolute minimum. If the best solution is *hard* then please explain it sloooow

Comment: The `Equals` method is not available when writing linq directly against the DB. Also the DB collation defines whether the comparison is performed with or without culture/case, you don't need to specify it when making the query

Comment: Im afraid I don't really understand the distinction your making, which is in to say, I'm an idiot. Can you re-word this for me at all, as I said, Im VERY new to linq and database applications and I'm still unsure of the exact terminology

Answer (score 1):

Your two requirements could be expressed as:

```
bool familyExists = db.Users.Any(u => u.familyID == famID);
bool emailTakenAlready = db.Users.Any(u => u.emailAddress == email);
```

These seem to be *independent* requirements, so you can do separate queries for them.

You can certainly use a logical not (`!`)  in Linq queries where it makes sense, it's just a matter of personal style.

Comment: Whilst this seems like the it will work im not certain performing multiple queries is exactly effiecient, but then my knowledge of linq is rather...limited so who am I to judge eh?

Comment: you want to check if the email matches *any* email in the system already, right? (Not just the one where the family id matches)

Comment: then a combined query won't work since your conditions are conflicting

Comment: Fair enough, so far linq seems really powerful and I guess I was hoping for this (or some similar) functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it like this:

```
    public bool JoinCalendar(int famID, string email)
    {
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            var exists = db.Users.Any(u => u.familyID == famID && u.emailAddress != email);
            if (exists)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //stuff
            return true;
        }
    }
```

It should also be most efficient as that query can be optimized on by the database.

Comment: This seems exactly like the type of functionality I am looking for. It does seem rather effiecient and its certianly clean looking, thanks!